# difference of typical usage of request client and RoutingSlip courier in masstransit

Tags: microservices, masstransit, routing-slip, masstransit-courier

I know for distributed  and sequential services we are using RoutingSlip courier. imagine I have scenario which I want to  have a reuquest publisher we name it as apiPublisher which wants call a dbMicro to get some data  and after that  call another Micro to do some stuff and then calling dbmicro to insert new data there and after all back the response to my publisher. so I'm going to create a rout and activities like that:

```
 private RoutingSlip CreateRoutingSlip(ConsumeContext<AccountModel> context)
            {
                var builder = new RoutingSlipBuilder(NewId.NextGuid());
                builder.AddSubscription
                    (context.ReceiveContext.InputAddress,
                        RoutingSlipEvents.Completed
                        | RoutingSlipEvents.Faulted);
                builder.AddVariable("AccountId", context.Message.AccountId);
                builder.AddVariable(nameof(context.RequestId), context.RequestId);
                builder.AddVariable(nameof(context.ResponseAddress), context.ResponseAddress);
                builder.AddVariable(nameof(context.FaultAddress), context.FaultAddress);
                builder.AddVariable("Request", context.Message);
                var dbQueueName = _formatter.
                    ExecuteActivity<SetAuthenticatedRequestWithDbActivity, AccountModel>();
    
                builder.AddActivity(nameof(SetAuthenticatedRequestWithDbActivity)
                    , new Uri($"queue:{dbQueueName}"), new
                {
                        AccountId = context.Message.AccountId,                
                });
                var apiQueueName = _formatter.ExecuteActivity<CallCampaignTpTestMicro, SpecialOfferActivePackageRequestModel>();
                builder.AddActivity("specialOffer", new Uri($"queue:{apiQueueName}"), new
                {
                    TelNum = "09195847189",
                    OfferId = "1",
                    ChoiceNo = "1",
    
                    Gateway = context.Message.Gateway,
                    HeaderNo = "1",
                    ChannelId = "1",
                });
                //next activity ...
                var dbResult = new AccountModel()
                {
                    AccountId = context.Message.AccountId,               
                };
                builder.AddVariable("Model", dbResult);
                return builder.Build();
            }
```

Now I want to know what is difference if I just simply call each this micro in my consumer after calling each other for example doing this:

```
var massResult= await _massClientRequest.GetResponse<AuthenticatePaymentResponeModel>
                (new AuthenticatePaymentRequestModel
                {
                    AccountRequest = context.Arguments.AccountRequest,
                    MyRequestedUrl = context.Arguments.MyRequestedUrl,
                    UserId = context.Arguments.UserId,                    

                });
            var res = massResult.Message;
var nextMasResult  =  await _massClientRequest.GetResponse<PaymentBankResponseModel>
               (new PaymentBankRequestModel
               {
                   BankeName = bankeName,
                   MyRequestUrl = context.Arguments.MyRequestUrl,
                   NewUrl = context.Arguments.NewUrl,
               });
 var 2ndRes= nextMasResult.Message;
if (2ndRes.IsSuccess){
var lastMasResult  =  await _massClientRequest.GetResponse<mymodel>
               (new mymodelReq
               {
                   BankeName = bankeName,
                   MyRequestUrl = context.Arguments.MyRequestUrl,
                   NewUrl = context.Arguments.NewUrl,
               });
```

is this scenario not working well and in order? what is the benefits of first approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing slip pattern is a *saga* (in the original sense of the paper) that offers additional features including:

- Compensation of previously executed routing slip activities
- Reduced message delays due to fewer messages, one less per additional activity
- Dynamic itinerary changes by activities so that behavior can be reactive to argument content

There is also a `RoutingSlipRequestProxy` and `RoutingSlipResponseProxy` which can be used to provide a standard request client entry point to a routing slip transaction. This allows the original API to use the request client to initiate the transaction and then handle the success/failure of that transaction as a result/fault combination (or result/bad-result pair).

Comment: with all respect to you master, I diss agree.  I am not getting your point for your first reason I have this answer that I can Compensation if  my request fails when I call first micro manually and others also are more easier if I don't write them in routing slip I guess there is one more big reason

Comment: I pointed out the reasons to use a routing slip transaction instead of doing multiple requests in order. Routing slips will be faster to execute, due to fewer message delay. But do whatever works for you.

Comment: So you mean this is faster than simple one many thanks.